# date format in aggregate command

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame named cut like this

```
date             Open      AAPL.High        ABT.High       ACN.High
0007-01-04  -0.10089875  -0.730226369      1.524297464    0.619697524
0007-01-05  0.122753233   0.244001748     -0.478851673   -0.646728204
0007-01-08  -0.64223987   0.405351183      0.23971246     1.048819618
0007-01-09  0.253708795   7.179369202      1.071651455    0.187090794
```

I used this formula to get monthly maximum values

```
cut$date <- as.Date(cut$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
RMax <- aggregate(cut[,-1],
                  by=list(Month=format(cut$date,"%y-%m")),
                  FUN=max)
```

but now I want to find bi monthly, tri monthly, or even 45 days maximum return value. How Can I edit this formula?

Comment: Naming your data frame `return` is an accident waiting to happen. As for creating monthly (bi, tri, 45mins, etc), use `cut`

Comment: Sorry, Can not perceive your message.

Comment: `return` is an existing function in R. It's a bad practise to name objects with already existing function names

Comment: o I understand. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Try to find out the range of your time span (max_date - min_date) then find out how many days are in this range (let say it is N). Then, if you want to calculate on a bi-monthly basis, split date would be N/2, so first month interval would be [min_date + N/2] and the second one is [N/2 + max_date]. In other words you may want to create a variable that splits the sample based on your needs whether you want to calculate every 7, 15 days etc.

Comment: But transaction days are not same in each time span.

Comment: What do you mean by "no the same"?

Comment: for example in March number trading days may 25 and in February it may 22.

Comment: `cut` is also an existing function in `R`. Suggestion: choose `prices` or `stock`.